# Scroll event only fire when scrolling top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll function. It needs to alert when you scroll to bottom. Strangely, it only alerts when you scroll to top. What is the correct way to make it work when you scroll at bottom.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    alert();
  });
});
```

Comment: Typo: Extra `}` after your `if` condition code block. Remove that and your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/d14emew6/. Tip, first thing to do when JS code doesn't work as you expect is to check the console for errors.

Comment: In my Experience the jQuery height() function often does not return 100% accurate values. Could be that is an issue. Use console.log to log your heights and offsets

Comment: Ok thanks. Firebug ?

Comment: @user198989 I am kinda confused. You want the code to be running once the user scrolls up right, instead of scrolling down, so does my answer suit your needs or? Coz I don't understand why it is "wrong". `:)`

Comment: No, I want it to be worked when user scrolled at the bottom.

Comment: I have tried Rory's script, on the fiddle, it works, but on my webpage it still run when you scroll to top. Thats so weird. Does jquery versions play a role on that ?

Comment: @user198989 Tell me once again? So, the user has to be in the bottom, and if he scrolls top, then it should trigger, is it?

Comment: Nope :) When user scrolls to bottom, it should run. no scroll to top I want. Its simple.

Comment: @user198989 Simple - I will jump from my building. LoL. `When user scrolls to bottom, it should run.` - and question: `Scroll event only fire when scrolling top` - They are contradictory!

Comment: This is the PROBLEM > Scroll event only fire when scrolling top"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag to keep the current scroll or update it and then check the current position:

```
$(function () {
  cur = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < cur) {
      // Scrolled Up!
    } // Remove the extra `);` here.
  });
});
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I don't think this is what the OP was asking to do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Er... What do you think? Should I delete this?

Comment: Probably best to as the actual issue is only a typo.

Comment: Yay! Now it is gone. `:)` Ah, but didn't know the reason at all! `:(`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
  alert();
 }  //Remove from here
});
```

Remove `)` after the end of `if` block.